# R: plot functions followed by readline()

Tags: r

I want to plot different variables against `mpg` in data `mtcars`, I want to plot them one by one, and wait for my any input for next plot, so I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
vars = list(quote(wt), quote(cyl), quote(disp))
plot_fun <- function(var) {
  qplot(mpg, eval(var), data=mtcars)
  input <- readLines(n=1)
}
lapply(vars, plot_fun)
```

it doesn't plot anything, anybody can show me the correct way?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is that with ggplot2 you need to do `print(qplot(...))` when the plotting function is called from within another function.

Here's your code modified to work in the way that you want.

```
library(ggplot2)
vars = list(quote(wt), quote(cyl), quote(disp))
plot_fun <- function(var) {
  ## this is what the `plot.lm` function uses to pause between plots; par(ask = TRUE) does the same thing
  devAskNewPage(TRUE) 

  print(qplot(mpg, eval(var), data=mtcars)) ## wrapping qplot in print makes the plot actually appear

  flush.console() ## this makes sure that the display is current
  devAskNewPage(FALSE)
}
lapply(vars, plot_fun)
```